# RMarkdown is not referencing tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

Somehow my RMarkdown document is not crossreferencing tables or figures. Here is a stripped down version of my document.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "01/04/2022"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

```
var1<-sample(LETTERS)
tab1<-table(var1)
```

My table is in Table \@ref{tab:tab1}

```
library(knitr)
kable(tab1, caption="my table")
```

AS we see in Figure \@ref{fig:plot1}

```
plot(seq(1,10,1))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to cross reference tables and plots in rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462761/how-to-cross-reference-tables-and-plots-in-rmarkdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your `tab1` in the code chunk like this `{r tab1}`. And use `()` instead of `{}` for your `@ref`. In that case it reference to your figures and tables. You can use the following code:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "01/04/2022"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

My table is in Table \@ref(tab:tab1)

```{r tab1, echo =FALSE}
var1<-sample(LETTERS)
tab1<-table(var1)

library(knitr)
kable(tab1, caption="my table")
```

\newpage

AS we see in Figure \@ref(fig:plot1)

```{r plot1, fig.cap ="plot", echo=FALSE}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .2, .1))
plot(seq(1,10,1))
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see on the image, when you click on `1` in will go to your table.